# router on a stick and VRRP on the same router and full redundancy possible?

Tags: trunk, redundancy, vrrp

The routers on a stick are running VRRP on g0/0.10, g0/0.20 and g0/0.30.
On switches, ports fa0/1-8 are on VLAN 10, fa0/23 and fa0/24 are configured as trunk port, with allowed VLANs 10, 20 and 30.

Show VRRP on HQ2 shows that all VRRP are as master, but on HQ1, they show as init, router are 2900 running IOS 15.1 and switch are 3560 running IOS 12.2,
I had the router on a stick running on 1 router and 1 switch with no problem and also VRRP running on a single switch with no problem, but there is something I do not understand here!  there is no other config on router and switches.
address on HQ2 have been change to x.x.x.253. 
config HQ1

```
 HQ1>show run
          ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

HQ1>ena
Current configuration : 1712 bytes  
version 15.4  
hostname HQ1  
ip cef  
redundancy  
interface GigabitEthernet0/0  
 no ip address  
 duplex auto  
 speed auto  
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10  
 encapsulation dot1Q 10  
 ip address 192.168.222.254 255.255.255.0  
 vrrp 1 ip 192.168.222.100 
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.20  
 encapsulation dot1Q 20  
 ip address 192.168.223.254 255.255.255.0  
 vrrp 2 ip 192.168.223.100  
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.30  
 encapsulation dot1Q 30 native  
 ip address 192.168.224.254 255.255.255.0  
 vrrp 3 ip 192.168.224.100  
interface GigabitEthernet0/1  
 ip address 200.100.0.14 255.255.255.252  
 duplex auto  
 speed auto  
interface Serial0/0/0  
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.252  
 clock rate 2000000
```

Configuration on the other router is the same except that address for g0/0.10 .20 and .30 terminate with 253 instead of 254 and of course the address for the serial connection is different. also discover a bad port on the switch so both VRRP are saying master now, so they do not communicate.

[image]

```
HQ1(config-subif)#do show vrrp  
GigabitEthernet0/0.10 - Group 1  
  State is Backup  
  Virtual IP address is 192.168.222.100  
  Virtual MAC address is 0000.5e00.0101  
  Advertisement interval is 1.000 sec  
  Preemption enabled  
  Priority is 100  
  Master Router is 192.168.222.253, priority is 150  
  Master Advertisement interval is 1.000 sec  
  Master Down interval is 3.609 sec (expires in 3.369 sec)  

GigabitEthernet0/0.20 - Group 2  
  State is Backup  
  Virtual IP address is 192.168.223.100  
  Virtual MAC address is 0000.5e00.0102  
  Advertisement interval is 1.000 sec  
  Preemption enabled  
  Priority is 100  
  Master Router is 192.168.223.253, priority is 150  
  Master Advertisement interval is 1.000 sec  
  Master Down interval is 3.609 sec (expires in 3.153 sec)  

GigabitEthernet0/0.30 - Group 3  
  State is Master  
  Virtual IP address is 192.168.224.100  
  Virtual MAC address is 0000.5e00.0103  
  Advertisement interval is 1.000 sec  
  Preemption enabled  
  Priority is 100  
  Master Router is 192.168.224.254 (local), priority is 100  
  Master Advertisement interval is 1.000 sec  
  Master Down interval is 3.609 sec  

HQ2#show vrrp  
GigabitEthernet0/0.10 - Group 1  
  State is Master  
  Virtual IP address is 192.168.222.100  
  Virtual MAC address is 0000.5e00.0101  
  Advertisement interval is 1.000 sec  
  Preemption enabled  
  Priority is 150  
  Master Router is 192.168.222.253 (local), priority is 150  
  Master Advertisement interval is 1.000 sec  
  Master Down interval is 3.414 sec  

GigabitEthernet0/0.20 - Group 2  
  State is Master  
  Virtual IP address is 192.168.223.100  
  Virtual MAC address is 0000.5e00.0102  
  Advertisement interval is 1.000 sec  
  Preemption enabled  
  Priority is 150  
  Master Router is 192.168.223.253 (local), priority is 150  
  Master Advertisement interval is 1.000 sec  
  Master Down interval is 3.414 sec  

GigabitEthernet0/0.30 - Group 3  
  State is Master  
  Virtual IP address is 192.168.224.100  
  Virtual MAC address is 0000.5e00.0103  
  Advertisement interval is 1.000 sec  
  Preemption enabled  
  Priority is 150  
  Master Router is 192.168.224.253 (local), priority is 150  
  Master Advertisement interval is 1.000 sec  
  Master Down interval is 3.414 sec
```

Comment: How do you have the routers with the same addresses? Each router needs its own address. You should also edit your question to include the router configurations.

Comment: It appears you have some misconfiguration on the switches. If the VRRP routers can't communicate on the LAN, each will think it's the master. You should make sure that you set the VRRP priorities and the STP priorities so that layer-2 and layer-3 traffic will flow the same direction. The router with the high VRRP priority should connect to the switch with the low STP priority.

Comment: @Ron  Maupin   I found a bad port on f0/24 on one switch, that is why it was staying at init. just to be sure f0/23 and f0/24 should be set as trunk right ?   I will only be able to continue tomorrow as the place is closed

Comment: OK. You should post an answer and accept it, otherwise the question just keeps popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: @Ron Maupin    Doesn't  posting an answer terminate the tread ? because it is not solve yet. just the init thing is gone

Comment: It doesn't terminate it, and it's not a thread, but I thought you really had an answer with the bad port. Anyone can answer any question at any time, including questions with accepted answers, and the person asking the question is free to change the acceptance at any time, too. It's just that questions with unaccepted answers keep coming back to the top every few weeks, even those answered by the person asking.

Comment: OK, I am still having a problem with this, the bad port only prevented the VRRP status from going beyond init.
both router shows VRRP status as master, so VRRP is not working.

Comment: How are you checking which is master? Are you sure you are looking at it per instance? You have 3 VRRP instance's running and I am not sure why. You could accomplish the same with less complexity with just the one instance and give your router less to process as well. If you could edit your original question and include the output of show VRRP perhaps?

Comment: @SleepyMan     I have 3 vlan, so I have 3 different subnets (servers, IP phone and PC), so I need 3 gateway address right ?

Comment: Yes you do need 3 gateway addresses but I don't think you need 3 instances of VRRP. You can assign the same instance to multiple subnets with no problems. For insance, I have one customer with over 300+ VLANS and using MSTP to direct specific spanning tree domains to a specific VRRP instance but we only use 2 VRRP instances to manage the lot. If you post your output for VRRP, we can help you a bit more.

Comment: @SleepyMan     config interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 192.168.222.254 255.255.255.0
 vrrp 1 ip 192.168.222.100
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 192.168.223.254 255.255.255.0
 vrrp 2 ip 192.168.223.100
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30 native
 ip address 192.168.224.254 255.255.255.0
 vrrp 3 ip 192.168.224.100 both router have same config except ip address of course

Comment: @SleepyMan     VRRP shown, for some reason g0/0.30 is master on both side! How can that be, it is the same physical wire and only very basic config was entered. also if I try to enter a subinterface into group 1 (int g0/0.20) I have the following error: HQ2(config-subif)#vrrp 1 ip 192.168.223.100
% Cannot create new VRRP group

Comment: Can you ping the sub-interface address of each router from the other router? So ping the non virtual address from HQ1 to HQ2 on that VLAN30 subnet? It almost looks like there isn't a layer 2 adjecency for this vlan so the routers are not seeing each other for that instance. How about shutting down the vlan interface on one router and bring it back up?

Comment: @SleepyMan     Ilooks like you are absolutly right, I just deleted everything from both switch,reload and reconfig them, and at startup I have:*Mar  1 00:05:12.618: %SW_MATM-4-MACFLAP_NOTIF: Host 0000.5e00.0103 in vlan 1 is flapping between port Fa0/22 and port Fa0/24
*Mar  1 00:05:13.557: %SW_MATM-4-MACFLAP_NOTIF: Host 0000.5e00.0101 in vlan 10 is flapping between port Fa0/22 and port Fa0/24 and those correspond to the virtual MAC of VRRP group1 and 3

Comment: @SleepyMan     from HQ2: Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/1/1 ms
HQ2#ping 192.168.222.254
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.222.254, timeout is 2 seconds:
.!!!!
Success rate is 80 percent (4/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/1/1 ms
HQ2#ping 192.168.223.254
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.223.254, timeout is 2 seconds:
.....
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)
HQ2#ping 192.168.224.254
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.224.254, timeout is 2 seconds:
.!!!!
Success rate is 80 percent (4/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/1/1 ms

Comment: @SleepyMan     from HQ1 same result 2 out of 3): HQ1#ping 192.168.222.253
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.222.253, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/1/4 ms
HQ1#ping 192.168.223.253
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.223.253, timeout is 2 seconds:
.....
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)
HQ1#ping 192.168.224.253
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.224.253, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/1/4 ms

Comment: my 3 virtual addresses are pingable from both switch

Comment: Have you tried shutting down the interface on HQ2 and bring it back up for that VLAN?

Comment: I do not know what happen, but I had one sub-interface (G0/0.30) that was was showing up as master on both side, How can that be? Same physical wire and same physical interface. everything is OK today! I can bring down the complete interface or a sub-interface and everything is switching correctly.

Comment: @SleepyMan     Yes, I beleived i tried it, but it would stay the same,   problem went away when I added some interfaces onto another VLAN (or maybe i worked too late and I just do not rememer  shuting down on the interface. Everything is OK now thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the problem, for some reason erasing the startup-config did not really erased everything, So I went in rommon and reset HQ2 to factory default and it is working.

Comment: After you erase a startup configuration, you must reload the device before configuring it. Also, that doesn't erase the VLAN database on a switch.

Comment: @RonMaupin     reload was done, but VLAN info was not erase, I will try that to solve my last weird problem

Comment: You can go into VLAN database mode from the enable prompt, and you can fix the VLAN database.

Comment: @RonMaupin     Since I have the  startup config in notepad++, I deleted the startup and vlan.dat and I am reloading both of my switch right now

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.